# Intuition behind symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am having a hard time understanding the intuition behind symmetric groups, and in particular, their elements. Consider the group $S_3$, with elements $id, (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2).$ Now, I fully understand that the group needs 6 elements since there are $3!$ ways to rearrange six elements, what I do not understand is the norm where these elements are used, or how I am to remember it without memorizing it, which is not convenient (nor good habit) at all. The most direct way of answering my question would be to answer this thoroughly: if $(2, 3)$ is an element of $S_3$, why isn't $(2, 3, 1)$?

Comment: It is. It just happens to be one of those elements already mentioned.

Comment: $(1,2,3)=(2,3,1)=(3,2,1)$  Also, $(1,2)=(2,1)$, etc....

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven By (3,2,1) you mean (3,1,2).

Comment: What is the difference between "remember" and "memorize"?

Comment: Ha ha, yeah, I did mean (3,1,2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask about the element $(2,3,1)$. What this element means is that the second position is sent to the third position, the third to the first, and the first to the second. But notice this is the same as $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,1,2)$.

So $(2,3,1)$ is in $S_3$, and you'd already mentioned it - but you called it $(1,2,3)$ above.

Comment: That cleared it up, so the norm is just to list the lowest number first?

Comment: I have trouble calling it the "norm", but it sounds reasonable. When I write something in disjoint cycle notation (like when you multiple a few of these together), I often start with $1$, see where it goes, and so on, and then start with the smallest remaining number for the next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind say $S_3$ is just how many bijective map you can have from a set $\{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2,3\}$

I leave it to you that there can be $6$ such function, and you must write them explicitly to get a clear picture.

$f_1=Id,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6$ say and then we use usual composition of function as group operation.

$f_2=(123)$ say so $f_2$ sends $1\to2\to3\to1$

$(1,2)$ means $1\to2\to1$ and $3\to 3$

Comment: How is the number of elements of a group the intuition behind the group?